# Solving a transcendental equation with some parameters

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to solve a transcendental equation:

```
NSolve[
  a (1/2 
    (a Sqrt[1 - a^4/b^4 - a^2/b^2] + 
      (b^2 ArcSin[(a Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])/b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) + 
    1/2 (Y Sqrt[1 - (a^2 Y^2)/b^4 - Y^2/b^2] + 
      (b^2 ArcSin[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Y)/b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])) == 
  mg/(2 B), Y]
```

But it didn't work. I got this message:

> NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

Any suggestion for me to get a numerical solution or even an approximation?

Comment: I think it simply means it could not solve it. Try this much simpler equation `NSolve[x^a + x + b == 0, x]` and it gives `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.`. But why are you using `NSolve` and not `Solve`?  If you want to use `NSolve` , you can try using some numerical values for the other parameters involved, you'll have better chance of Mathematica solving it then.

Comment: btw, if `mg` is meant to be mass times gravity acceleration, then it should be `m g`

Comment: What are the ranges on the parameters?  Or just some example values for all of them?  Keep in mind it turns complex for certain values due to square root and arcsin.

Comment: I want to plot the solution Y(b), but idk how to start since Solve didn't work here either.

Comment: FWIW, this gives a solution: `Block[{a = 1/2, b = 2, mg = 1, B = 1}, 
 Solve[a (1/ 2 (a Sqrt[ 1 - a^4/b^4 - a^2/b^2] + (b^2 ArcSin[(a Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])/b^2]) / Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) + 1/2 (Y Sqrt[1 - (a^2 Y^2)/b^4 - Y^2/b^2] + (b^2 ArcSin[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Y)/b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])) == mg/(2 B), Y, Reals]]`

Comment: An example plot: `With[{a = 7/10, mg = 1, B = 1}, obj[b_?NumericQ] := Y /. First@FindRoot[a (1/2 (a Sqrt[1 - a^4/b^4 - a^2/b^2] + (b^2 ArcSin[(a Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])/b^2]) / Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) + 1/2 (Y Sqrt[1 - (a^2 Y^2)/b^4 - Y^2/b^2] + (b^2 ArcSin[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Y)/b^2]) / Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])) == mg/(2 B), {Y, 1 - a, 1 - a - 0.2 Sign[a - 1/2]}]; Plot[obj[b], {b, 0.5, 2}, PlotRange -> All]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you, it really helps!